# Let $A$ be a finite set. If $X \subseteq A$, then $X$ is finite.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Let $A$ be a finite set. If $X \subseteq A$, then $X$ is finite.

Proof:

Since $A$ is finite, there is some $n\in N$ such that $A$ ~ $[1,n]$ and there is some bijective map $f:A \to [1,n]$. Let's define a map $g : X \to f(X)$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Since $f$ is injective, so is $g$, and since the codomain of $g$ is $f(X)$, from the definition of image, $g$ is surjective and hence $g$ is bijective. Since $f(X) \subseteq [1,n]$, so there is some $k \in N$ such that $f(X)$ ~ $[1,k]$, and hence $X$ is finite.

*Note that the symbol ~ means that the the sets have the same cardinality*

---

So is there any flaw in the proof or some point that is not exactly clear or maybe unnecessarily explained etc. I'm hoping you guys can check the proof and give me some feedback about it in any aspect of the proof.

Comment: With the most recent edits, it seems fine to me.

Comment: @JMoravitz After reading a couple of time, I realised that I should probably  also prove that if $f(X) \subseteq [1,n]$, then there is some $k\in N$ such that $f(X)$ ~ $[1,k]$, don't you think ?